# Flashlight dismantle: why is a small cylinder of ferrite used?

Tags: batteries, ferrite, ferrite-bead

After dismanteling a Petzl flashlight, I found a small cylinder of ferrite.

Why is it used? For what?

The flashlight used 3 AAA batteries so the ferrite bead doesn't seem to be used for reducing high-frequency (and it's quite far from the PCB and the wires).

It is inside the plastic case without any electrical connection. There is just a small hole that leads to the battery case. The ferrite doesn't touch the battery.

[image]

[image]

The flashlight:

[image]

Sources for the images: [light-test.info](http://www.light-test.info/en/headlamps/17-petzl-tikka-xp-cree-xp-g-mod) , [thereminworld.com](http://www.thereminworld.com/Forums/T/31550/petzl-tikka-xp-rebulb)

Comment: Probably a magnet so you can stick the flashlight to your refrigerator or tool chest.

Comment: Does it even connect electrically to the circuit? It's impossible to see from the pictures what it is used for.

Comment: @Justme, sorry for not being more precise. I have edited my question: it is not electrically connected to the circuit.

Comment: For pushing the first battery out.

Comment: @Andyaka, no that can't be because the battery are removed from the other side (like normal battery)

Comment: It could just be a weight to change the balance or a vestigial design feature left over from another model or revision.

Comment: Presumably it has a water/gas tight case.  Could it be for absorbing gasses, since there is a vent to the battery compartment?  Are you sure it is ferrite?

Comment: @MatthewWhited, it's a simple flashlight so there isn't any weight balance needed.

Comment: @HandyHowie, it's a simple flashlight, so it's no gas tight but probably a bit waterproof. I am not sure it's ferrite, I got this info from the light-test.info website. (added as a source at the end of my question)

Comment: You don’t know any of that which is why you are asking.

Comment: @MatthewWhited, do you mean I don't know anything concerning the weight balance? I forgot to add a photo of the flashlight, but I added it since: the flashlight isn't part of a precision device, it comes on a headband, so the customer is supposed to walk with it or even to run. I don't think a weight balance would make sense with this usage. But if you mean concerning the ferrite, then you are right, I don't know.

Comment: Petzl makes equipment for rock climbers some of them are insanely pedantic when it some to equipment including weight and balance.  And again it could just be something required for a different model that wasn’t deleted when they made a modification for sale.